# Skyscanner Flight search API with Ruby on rails6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

Hi i'm working on flight ticket website(search cheap flight ticket),using Skyscanner Flight API. Basically i copied this API [tutorial](https://rapidapi.com/blog/how-to-use-an-api-with-ruby/) to implement flight search function. However it only shows blank result in search.html.erb. In tutorial's form page you only fill out country name in form using different API. I'm stuck now and wonder how to implement search action & find_ticket action to take several parameter from index page's form and shows result properly.

**Environment** Rails:6.02 Ruby:2.65 RapidApi:skyscannerFlightSearch(i'm using RakutenRapidAPI)

**Routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'travel#index'
  get '/search' => 'travel#search'
  resources :messages
end
```

**travel_controller.rb**

```
class TravelController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def search
   tickets = find_ticket(params[:country])
   unless tickets
    flash.now[:alert] = 'ticket not found'
    return render action: :index
   end
   @ticket = tickets.first
  end

  private

  def find_ticket(name)
  request_api(
    "https://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com/apiservices/browsequotes/v1.0/#{URI.encode(name)}"
  )
  end

  def request_api(url)
    response = Excon.get(
      url,
      headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Host' => URI.parse(url).host,
        'X-RapidAPI-Key' => Rails.application.credentials.rapid[:XXXX_key]
      }
    )
    return nil if response.status != 200
    JSON.parse(response.body)
  end
end
```

**Views/travel/index.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 mt-5">
      <% if flash[:alert] %>
        <div class="alert alert-warning"><%= flash[:alert] %></div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="mx-auto mt-5" style="width: 400px">
        <%= form_with(url: search_path, method: 'get', local: true) do %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= label_tag :country, 'country '%>
            <%= text_field_tag :country, nil, placeholder: 'US', class: 'form-control' %>
            <%= label_tag :currency, 'currency'%>
            <%= text_field_tag :currency, nil, placeholder: 'USD', class: 'form-control' %>
            <%= label_tag :locale, 'locale'%>
            <%= text_field_tag :locale, nil, placeholder: 'en-US', class: 'form-control' %>
            <%= label_tag :originplace, 'originplace'%>
            <%= text_field_tag :originplace, nil, placeholder: 'SFO-sky', class: 'form-control' %>
            <%= label_tag :destinationplace, 'destinationplace'%>
            <%= text_field_tag :destinationplace, nil, placeholder: 'JFK-sky', class: 'form-control' %>
            <%= label_tag :outbounddate, 'outbounddate'%>
            <%= text_field_tag :outbounddate, nil, placeholder: '2020-02-01', class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
          <%= button_tag 'Search', class: 'btn btn-success btn-block' %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**views/travel/search.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h4>Ticket info</h4>
      <dl>
        <dt>PlaceId</dt>
        <dd><%= @ticket['PlaceId'] %></dd>
        <dt>lataCode</dt>
        <dd><%= @ticket['IataCode'] %></dd>
        <dt>Name</dt>
        <dd><%= @ticket['Name'] %></dd>
        <dt>SkyscannerCode</dt>
        <dd><%= @ticket['SkyscannerCode'] %></dd>
        <dt>CityName</dt>
        <dd><%= @ticket['CityName'] %></dd>
      </dl>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you check whether you are getting a valid response from skyscanner API or not. Use `byebug` and see the values of `@ticket` and `tickets` in your rails console

Comment: Hi Ashutosh thanks for reply. Both @ticket & tickets are nil . Also no response from skyscanner API.  I guess find_ticket action is not working.